# geolocation with both bing and google because of Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, geolocation

Hi I am currently playing with geolocation and it works great with everything except IE as it doesn't seem to support Google and wants to use Bing does anyone know how to make the directions IE friendly...its been bugging me for days!!

Heres my code:

```
function fallback() {
    var myOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.43255949795703, - 0.461750328540802),
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("Map_Canvas"),
    myOptions);

    var markerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(51.43255949795703, - 0.461750328540802);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: markerPos,
        map: map,
        title: "The Harpers Hairdressing"
    });
}

function initGeolocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        // Call getCurrentPosition with success and failure callbacks 
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);
    } else {
        fallback()
    }
}
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function success(position) {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
    position.coords.longitude);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: coords
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("Map_Canvas"),
    myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    calcRoute();
}

function calcRoute() {
    var start = coords;
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(51.43255949795703, - 0.461750328540802);
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
    });
}

function fail() {
    fallback();
}
```

Comment: What happens in IE? Are there any errors?

Comment: No in IE it just shows the fallback and just displays the final location you can view it working at http://harpers.everythingcreative.co.uk/contact

Answer (score 0):

A quick search reveals IE9 is supposed to support geolocation, but it is not as accurate as other browsers. For IE8 and older it looks like you would have to use a "polyfill", e.g. [Webshims](http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/demos/geolocation.html).

Comment: That has all gone over my head. I'm currently testing on IE9 and it relies on the fallback but works correctly on every other browser