# HTML5 geolocation with fallback

Tags: html, geolocation

I am trying this for Geolocation.

https://gist.github.com/366184

It works fine in Chrome, FF and IE9 but in IE 8 I get

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'watchPosition': object is null or undefined
```

How do I use this? It just pasted the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be bad support for this in IE8, you are not the only one have trouble with google geolocation and IE8

[Here is one similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451150/geolocation-with-both-bing-and-google-because-of-internet-explorer)